# Access redbeanphp object property with twig

Tags: php, twig, fuelphp, redbean

This could be a simple problem but is messing my head out.

The thing is I'm doing a project with fuelPHP, RedBean and Twig. All seems to work fine and I'm progressing really well with this framework.

The problem I encounter which I've not find any solution yet is that Twig it's not able to access `{{object.property}}` if I get the object from redbean. Which is totally strange because if I use my own MVC framework the exact same code (Twig+Redbean also) works.

For example

```
public function action_messages() {
    $room = \Uri::segment(3);
    $this->data['messages'] = \R::find('message', 'room = ? ORDER BY id', array($room));
    
    // This is working because it's converting each row to array
    /*foreach($this->data['messages'] as $id => $message)
        $this->data['messages'][$id] = $message->export();*/
    
    return \Response::forge(\View::forge('chat/messages.twig', $this->data));
}
```

The thing works as expected if I get the export as an array but not as an object.

```
{%for message in messages%}
     <b>{{message.user.id}}</b>{{message.datetime}}: {{message.text}}
{%endfor%}
```

I'm really lost with this. So I would appreciate any possible help.

Edit: (More info)

If I put

```
{%for message in messages%}
{{message}}<br/>
{%endfor%}
```

I get this output from the Var.

```
{"id":"23","text":"A test","room":"1","datetime":"2012-10-05 15:32:36","user_id":"1"}
```

Comment: maybe its just how I'm looking at this and based on how I use twig, but i dont see how messages is even fed to twig to process. I see $this->data, unless I'm wrong that won't work as your giving it the array and only using the key in the twig loop logic. something seems missing here.

Comment: The $this->data is a public array in the class. What did you mean with twig loop logic exactly?
I really have to dig inside this because it makes me feel stupid or something (I have 5 projects where is working as expected, 2 of them with fuelPHP not)

Comment: I finally found the problem (Still not solved) But for some reason Twig is dumping the var content as String not as an object or array. `13 => string '{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;13&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;adsadsads&quot;,&quot;room&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;datetime&quot;:&quot;2012-10-05 14:29:08&quot;,&quot;user_id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}' (length=188)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got it working.

The problem was in the Twig config in the FuelPHP framework.

The auto_encode parameter does the conversion of json to array in case of object properties. So you MUST set it to false (It's true by default).

Adjust your config to get something like this.

```
// TWIG ( http://www.twig-project.org/documentation )
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
'View_Twig' => array(
    'include' => APPPATH.'vendor'.DS.'Twig'.DS.'Autoloader.php',
    'auto_encode' => false, // Remember to set this to false
    'views_paths' => array(APPPATH.'views'),
    'delimiters' => array(
        'tag_block'     => array('left' => '{%', 'right' => '%}'),
        'tag_comment'   => array('left' => '{#', 'right' => '#}'),
        'tag_variable'  => array('left' => '{{', 'right' => '}}'),
    ),
    'environment' => array(
        'debug'                => false,
        'charset'              => 'utf-8',
        'base_template_class'  => 'Twig_Template',
        'cache'                => APPPATH.'cache'.DS.'twig'.DS,
        'auto_reload'          => true,
        'strict_variables'     => false,
        'autoescape'           => false,
        'optimizations'        => -1,
    ),
    'extensions' => array(
        'Twig_Fuel_Extension'
    ),
),
```

And it will work like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

I looked into Twig for you but it's way too complex (needless) to dive in. 
I dont know about Twig. But have you tried to use the template engine written by the  author of RedBeanPHP?

http://gabordemooij.com/se/

It's simple. But different, like RedBeanPHP. Gabor is always different ;) .

Comment: Hi Gabor (I really like your ORM simple fast and accurate) I promise to give Stamp a try. But in this case I really need the power of Twig simplifies a lot of things.